# Unable to require Parse in react-native. 'Requiring unknown module "react-native"'

Tags: reactjs, parse-platform, react-native

I have the following installed with npm:

```
"dependencies": {
    "parse": "^1.9.1",
    "react-native": "0.32.0",
    "react-native-admob": "^1.1.5",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "redux": "3.5.2"
  },
```

I am unable to require Parse into my react-native app by using: `var Parse = require('parse/react-native')`

I get this error:

[image]

The file `react-native` IS inside `node_modules/parse/react_native.js` but my app wont find it. I have tried reseting the emulator, deleting and reinstalling `node_modules`.

The error is now a know issue: [Issue](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/342)

Comment: seems like a (now) known bug: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

Inside file `node_modules/parse/lib/react-native/StorageController.react-native.js` change this line:

`var _reactNative = require('react-native');`

to

`var _reactNative = require('../../../react-native');`

This is still an open issue in github:

This solution was found by @jaredwitt 
In:

> https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/342
>
> I was able to patch it by changing the following line in node_modules/parse/lib/react-native/StorageController.react-native.js

Comment: Bless your sweet beautiful heart!